# How do I change the textcolor on my website with buttons?

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering how I change entire text(paragraphs,links,title) on my website with buttons? 
I already managed to change background color on my site with Javascript:

```
 function chngebg (id)
{
    switch (id)
    {
        case 'b1':
            document.body.bgColor = "#0099FF";
            break;

        case 'b2':
            document.body.bgColor = "#FF6666";
            break;

        case 'b3':
            document.body.bgColor = "black";
            break;   

    }
}
```

But I dont know how to make it change the text on the site.
I had something like this in mind: http://www.codelifter.com/main/javascript/colorbuttonsPop.html

Here is my website (I'm new to this don't be harsh :P): alexander.araweb.se
(The buttons are currently displayed as [x]'s in the bottom of the page.)

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: It can be useful for you to learn how to use developer tools in your browser, so you can check how the things are done on the website you are browsing. Try to right click and "Inspect Element" or press F12. You can find html, css and js files..

Answer (score 0):

```
document.body.style.color = 'red';
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I actually tried it before but it doesnt change anything.Im using iFrames on my site - does that complicate things? thanks for the anwser though. :)

Comment: @user2280494 Using iFrames is really obsolete technique, try to avoid them.

Comment: Is there any other ways to change colors then or should I just remove the iframes and restart the website?

Comment: we need to see your page DOM to say that

Answer (score 0):

Everything will have to be changed individually.
There are two ways you can do this.

Either using CSS or using JavaScript.

**1. JavaScript**

Give everything that needs to be changed an id like this:

```
<h1 id="title"> Title </h1>
```

Then in JavaScript access everything through its id and change it in the function:

```
function changeStyleTwo()
{
  document.getElementById('title').style.color = 'blue';
}
```

**2. CSS**

Give everything that needs to be changed a class name like this:

```
<h1 class="title"> Title </h1>
```

In JavaScript, when the function is called, change the class name so CSS can change it accordingly like this:

```
function changeStyleTwo()
{
  var title = document.getElementByClassName('title');
  title.className = 'titleStyleTwo';
}
```

Then in CSS have different CSS styles for each different class.

```
.titleStyleOne
{
  color:red;
}

.titleStyleTwo
{
  color:blue;
}
```